# sin() in Java coming up with significantly different numbers than my calculator

Tags: java, trigonometry

I am implementing Math.sin() on a radian value I have calculated and was wondering if there is any technical reason that I receive a different number from java than from my calculator. The relevant code:

```
public static double sin(double angle){    
  angle = Math.toRadians(angle);
  return Math.sin(angle);
}
```

input: 35

output: 0.573576436351046

expected output, according to google: -0.42818266949

and I am simply printing the returned value of this. Could anyone tell me?

Comment: Show how you declared `angle`, and show some input values, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Without input, output and expected output we can't help you.

Comment: The output you are receiving is correct

Comment: Why might google be giving me the wrong output then? truly just curious

Comment: For 99% of real world cases it is enough to know only 5 digits of Pi or of any sin/con/tg. So if calculator's sin() differs form java's sin() at 5-th digit, it's fine.

Comment: Google uses radians where you are using degrees

Comment: my Windows Calculator says that sin(35) is `0,57357643635104609610803191282616`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I was simply reading from the google calculator. It's late.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are confusing degrees and radians

`35` degrees is approximately `0.611` radians, the sine of which is `0.573576436351046`

The sine of `35` *radians* is `-0.42818266949`

If you enter `sin(35)` in Google it will calculate the sine of `35` radians and will tell you it did so right above the result.

[image: Google Screen Capture]

Comment: If you enter `sin(35)` in Google it will calculate the sine of 35 _radians_ and will tell you it did so right above the result.

Comment: @DenisKokorin google uses radians as default unless you specifically say degrees

Comment: Awesome. Thanks all. I knew it was something just flying over my head like that. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @DenisKokorin *"there is no 35 radians it suppouse, that the value is in degrees"*-- negative result for sin(35°), really?